# Scrape MarketWatch in Google Sheets

Tags: swift

I am trying to scrape this: yet I have had no results!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=index(ImporthtML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/lmha","list",14),13,1)
```

To achieve a date format with say the above in A1:

```
=1*trim(right(A1,13))
```

Alternatively, replace `A1` in the second formula with the first formula - for a result occupying a single cell:

```
=1*trim(right(index(ImporthtML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/lmha","list",14),13,1),13))
```